# What is the purpose of adding SSH keys to GitHub?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am reading through a book that had me generate an SSH key and add it to GitHub. After doing so, the book simply states that we are ready to create a repository and push our code up. I am confused because I have never needed to do this to push up my code. So what purpose does this serve?

Comment: Keys are more secure than passwords. Especially if people use lame passwords. It also prevents your from having to type your password every time you run a command that references the public repo. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/is-using-a-public-key-for-logging-in-to-ssh-any-better-than-saving-a-password

Comment: You can also add multiple keys to the same account. If 5 people are sharing a password for the account, you can only block one of those people by changing the password and redistributing the new password to the other 4. With keys, each person gets their own key, and individual keys can be revoked without invalidating the others.

Comment: And the "people" in my previous comment don't have to be actual people; the same argument applies for multiple computers that you might use to access your own GitHub account, rather than sharing the same key across multiple computers.

Answer (score 4):

The ssh key generated lets github verify you are the one pushing code and not someone else who might be malicious or otherwise. They are less cumbersome and more secure than manually entering a username/password as well. I'm not sure how you previously used github but SSH keys are best practice way to secure your repo so I would recommend you continue to use this key in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Keys are basically decoupled passwords. Typically, there is a one-to-one mapping between passwords and accounts: each account has exactly one password, and each password is (or rather, should be) used with exactly one account.

However, any number of keys can be associated with a single account. This means you can have a different way of authenticating yourself from your personal computer, your work computer, your phone, your tablet, etc. If any one of those keys gets compromised, you can invalidate it without affecting the others.

This also allows for more secure account sharing: multiple maintainers can each have their own key for contributing to a shared repository.

Comment: this reason makes the most sense to me

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I was looking up the latest on git access after taking an 8-year break from development, so figured I can answer for posterity.

A great long description is here: [https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols][1]

In short, you can access files in your repo via a few protocols (transport channels, if you will): HTTPS, git, and ssh.

**HTTPS** needs username/password ("u/p"), but storing those securely is a problem. If the operating system provides secure storage, it can be used. GitHub Desktop Client, for example, stores your u/p in the Keychain secure storage provided by Mac OS. That's why you don't have to enter u/p every time you interact with repos on Github via the client app: it reads u/p from Keychain. You may ask, why is storing u/p a problem but sending over https isn't? Because of the "s" at the end - the server must provide a valid security certificate before the git app will attempt sending your u/p over the wire.

**ssh protocol** doesn't support anonymous requests, period. So it always, always needs a key to encrypt the data with. Since nerds created github they often use ssh so it's the default recommended way =) haha but seriously, once you use ssh a bit you'll find it easier anyway AND it doesn't require installation of any application. "Look, ma, I only use the terminal, no gui" is something we all aspire one day to say. I think. So it's great for when you remote into a server and need to clone a repo there. Why does ssh always encrypt? Well, you *could* have an infected router on the way, for example, that can literally inject malicious code into files that go through it. So you'd clone the repo, try to run the app and BAM, your computer is a zombie.

**git protocol** git's custom protocol that's really only for serving files with little overhead as it uses no ecnryption. So think of it as read-only ssh without security. You can't push to a repo over this protocol since, again, no authentication/security. This is not a protocol for public use, and basically you can just forget it exists and never use it (never type git:// in front of your repo names, e.g.  git clone git://lala/some_repo.git)

I hope that 5 years later this answer is useful to somebody ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Using the SSH key is highly recommended. Every user has a private and public keys, the private key remains on the system being used to access the remote system and is used to decrypt information that is exchanged in the SSH protocol. A public key is used to encrypt information that can be shared, and is used by the user and the remote server.