# Where is object.__new__ defined?

Tags: python-3.x, constructor, cpython, default-constructor, internals

Where can I find the source code for the implementation of `object.__new__`. It shows as "built-in". I would like to see how it works.

```
>>> object.__new__
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x822060>
```

Comment: It's not duplicate. I'm not asking how to do it. I'm asking where it is, and I found it. Not to mention that question is almost entirely about built-in code written in python not C internal functions

Comment: This would be off-topic as a request for a 3rd-party resource anyway. Stack Overflow does not need to be an index into every open-source code repository.

Comment: What part of resolution between built-in Python 3 functions and internal names is provided by any open-source code repository?
 And while you're at, perhaps you should be a little more self-critical if you think Stack Overflow **does** need to be a Q/A site for a proprietary open-source code repository https://stackoverflow.com/q/57171836/124486

Comment: @EvanCarroll The first answer pretty clearly links the repository and mentions where to find the C code for the built-ins. The other question asks "how to get" **and** "how to find" the source code which makes your question a subset of that question in my eyes.

Comment: @MSeifert It has exactly one sentence which is remotely related to this question *"However, many of the built-in types can be found in the Objects sub-directory of the Python source trunk."* Tell me how you go from that to `typeobject.c`.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Well, the `typeobject.c` is in the ["Objects sub-directory"](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Objects).

Comment: ... Yes, and that doesn't really help me because there are like 30 files in that directory many with 10k+ lines. And to say the least, `typeobject` is not what I look for when I'm playing around with objects. Especially when there is `object.c` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3's `object.__new__` is internal (built-in). It's not written in Python. You can find the C code for it as [`object_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/41c57b335330ff48af098d47e379e0f9ba09d233/Objects/typeobject.c#L3735) in `typeobject.c`.

Comment: So did you learn anything from that?  Most of the function appears to be checking parameters.  The action is at the end, `type->tp_alloc(type, 0);`  But without much study of the Python C-API that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @hpaulj That's just memory mgmt. I don't think that's the interesting stuff here. After I found `object.__new__` I wanted the constructor for all non-base objects which is `type_new` (afaik) in the same file. Basic point is that I don't see a way to make one object and instance of a *different* class.

Comment: `numpy.ndarray` uses a custom `__new__`.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#a-brief-python-primer-on-new-and-init